# How to change select tags value when element is deleted from array?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have `select` `tag` which takes values from `array` like this

```
<select class="groupForArchive" ng-model="selected.country">
      <option ng-selected= "{{country == selected.country}}" ng-repeat="country in countrynList" value={{country}}> {{ country.name }} </option>
    </select>
```

when I am deleting element from `array(countryList)` I am setting new value to this `tag` like this `$scope.selected.country = newValue`, but in `select box` I am getting free space like in this pictures.

before delete country from list

[image]

after delete country from list

[image]

and when I am taking `select` tag's `ng-model` I am getting correct `object` but I can not see it in my `select box` and I don't know which item is selected.

P.S `newValue` is array's another item(item from `countrynList`)

How can I fix it ?

Comment: When doing `$scope.selected.country = newValue`, this `newValue` is an element from the `countrynList` or a new one created by you (even with the same values)?

Comment: `newValue` is array's another item(item from countrynList)

Comment: Please share your code which does that. Reproducing it in a fiddle/plunker will be of great help.

Comment: this smell like a digest business. Try to wrap delete function with timeout, this for the digest cycle has enough time to is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Update AngularJS library to latest version and make changes, presented below:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){    
  $scope.countrynList = [  
    {name:'USA'}, {name:'Spain'}, {name:'France'}, {name:'Germany'}
  ]
  $scope.selected = {country: $scope.countrynList[0]};
  
  $scope.Delete = function(){    
    var index = $scope.countrynList.indexOf($scope.selected.country);
    $scope.countrynList.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.selected.country = $scope.countrynList[0];
  }  
})
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <select class="groupForArchive" ng-model="selected.country">
    <option ng-repeat="country in countrynList" ng-value='country'>
      {{country.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
  {{selected.country}}
  <br>
  <input type='button' ng-click='Delete()' value='Delete First'/>
</div>
```